# Enumerate Application Domains and its properties [MonitoringTotalProcessorTime..... ] for all .NET 4.0 processes

Tags: .net, process, appdomain

Enumerate all .NET Framework 4.0 Processes on a particular machine. And then enumerate Application Domains for those processes.

After enumerating Application Domains, fetch data about each Application Domain using following APIs.

AppDomain.MonitoringTotalProcessorTime

AppDomain.MonitoringTotalAllocatedMemorySize

AppDomain.MonitoringSurvivedMemorySize

We tried this using Mdbgcore.dll and mscoree.dll

However, we couldnt enumerate all the above properties of App Domains for each .NET Framework 4.0 process on a system.

Could anyone help me on this?

Many thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997285.aspx is your friend